# NotAuthorizedException what i get in object Challenge

Tags: java, http, challenge-response

As in title, what I get in Object Challenge which I get from `javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException`
and how i can take realm, host and type of authorization from it?

`Object challenge = notAuthorizedException.GetChallenges()[0];`

Comment: share the code snippet plz

Comment: It is more general question, but i add a code that can get a challenge from exception